How to get every textual channel with discord.js v14?
I'd like to know how to get every textual channels of a discord server to put them in a select menu.
I've already tried some things, but nothing worked expect one but was putting me vocal channels too. Here's the one that "worked" :
const channels3 = guild3.channels.fetch();
const jsp = channels3.filter(
    channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT'
);

const channelOptions3 = jsp.map(channel => ({
    label: channel.name,
    value: channel.id
}));


Here's an alternative way to get the list of all text channels.

The channel data is pushed in an array that is needed for select menu options.

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guild_id');
var array = [];
guild.channels.cache.filter((channel) => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT').forEach((channel) => {
    array.push({
        label: channel.name,
        description: channel.id,
        value: channel.id,
        emoji: null,
    });
});

Just a litte code snippet to send an embed with the select menu component. (May not work, something might need to be updated from v13 to v14)
const menu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
    .setCustomId('select-menu')
    .setPlaceholder('Select a channel')
    .addOptions(array);
const select_menu = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(menu);

message.channel.send({
    embeds: [], // Add your embed
    components: select_menu
}).then(async (msg) => {
    const select = async (i) => {
        if (i.customId !== 'select-menu') return;
        let { values } = i;
        let value = values[0]; // selected channel


        // do your staff here


        await i.deferUpdate();
        return i.message.edit({
            embeds: [], // updated embed
            // components: select_menu 
        });
    };
    const filter = (i) => {
        if (i.user.id !== message.author.id) return
        i.reply({
            embeds: [{
                title: `You can't use the menu!`,
                description: `Only ${message.author} can use that menu!`
            }],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    };

    const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
        filter,
        componentType: 'SELECT_MENU',
        time: 3e5,
    });
    collector.on('collect', select);
});

